# How to send an Email to limited number of recipients repeatedly?

Tags: ios, swift, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmailcomposer

I have an option to "invite all" in my device contacts email to use my iOS application through MFMailComposeViewController. Its working fine right now. But in my device, i stored 175 email contacts. So it takes time to show those email id's in bcc field. Like this,

[image]

So i decided to send 50 mails at a time. once first 50 mails sent then immediately i have to show same screen with next 50 email id's, like that i have send mails to all the contacts. In this scenario, i have to show mail compose screen for 4 times to send Email. Like this,

[image]

So Please give me some ideas to do this. My codings are,

```
@IBAction func act_InviteAllInContacts(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        var contactList : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
        contactList = addressBookClassObj.getContactNames() // contactList is an Array, which contains 175 email id's.
        var picker = MFMailComposeViewController()
        picker.mailComposeDelegate = self
        picker.setSubject("Subject Name")
        picker.setMessageBody("Hi! Checkout this app https://itun", isHTML: true)
        picker.setBccRecipients(contactList as [AnyObject])
        presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
```

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question

Comment: Why don't you use a web server maybe a PHP script to do this work. The server goes and does it in its own separate process once you invoke it. I would recommend putting such things on the server with a simple script.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? 50 or 175 contacts. It doesn't really matter.

Comment: @Christian - if 175 contact means, it took too many times to load those mail id's in recipient field.